# Cannot console.log API data, gives status code 300

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, next.js

I created these controller to fetch the images uploaded on cloudinary:

```
export const getImages = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const images = await Gallery.find();
    return res.status(200).json({ message: "Images Fetched", images });
    
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    res.status(300).json({ message: "something went wrong" });
  }
}
```

I get the api response on postman as follows which is the desired response, all things are correct here:

```
{
  "message": "Images Fetched",
  "images": [
    {
      "_id": "6447e9226133dc1d1866761d",
      "image": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dmrfkusal/image/upload/v1682434338/gallery/huweywhbhtctlnyvznhy.png",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

But when i call it on the next.js frontend:

```
 useEffect(()=>{
    const getImages = async () => {
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5001/api/gallery/getImages");
      
      console.log("heres the data",res)
      
  }
 getImages();
  },[])
```

I get this in the console:

```
Response {type: 'cors', url: 'http://localhost:5001/api/gallery/getImages', redirected: false, status: 300, ok: false, …}
body
: 
(...)
bodyUsed
: 
true
headers
: 
Headers {}
ok
: 
false
redirected
: 
false
status
: 
300
statusText
: 
"Multiple Choices"
type
: 
"cors"
url
: 
"http://localhost:5001/api/gallery/getImages"
```

the status code i get is 300, i don't get how to get the output on the frontend, i tried to work around but im getting stuck

Where am i going wrong in this?

Any code changes which i need to implement in order to successfull fetch the above api response on the frontend?

I want to fetch the uploaded images and display the images on the UI

Comment: You need `const data = await res.json()` to get the data.